# How can I take the first 3 digits of a text file into another text file

Tags: c#

I want to take the first 3 digits of the text file into another text file. My file is test.txt

```
195^20140212^0^H^000000^A
312^20140211^0^H^010000^A
312^20140211^0^H^020000^A
```

Where I only need to take the 195,312,312 in another text file. How can It be possible? I have tried the below but I am not able to save it to another text file.

```
string test = @"\\Fdrtse\POI\Debopam\test.txt";
var text = File.ReadAllLines(test);

while (text != null) {
    foreach(var line in text) {
        string[] dataArray = line.Split('^');
    }
}
```

Comment: And why are you not able to save it to another file? what is the error you get? or what is the current issue you have? Also I would suggest you to use `foreach (string line in text)` instead of your `while`.

Comment: After taking each line into the array how to take the 1st 3 digits and how to write it to another file. Please suggest.

Comment: You're not saying what your issue is at all.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @JohnP It doesn't matter, really http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 4):

```
var numbers = File.ReadLines("path").Select(line => line.Split('^').First());

File.WriteAllLines("otherFilePath", numbers);
```

Comment: Very concise solution, +1

Comment: Is it suppose to do inside the foreach statement?? because I need to take each and every lines in the text file.

Comment: @user3203633 No, you don't need `foreach`. these two lines doing exactly what you want. First read all lines, split each of them by `^`, select the first element which is your number, then write all these numbers to the another file.

Comment: File.Readlines is not supporting as I am using .net 2.0 and targetting .net 3.5

Answer (score 3):

```
File.WriteAllLines(outFile, File.ReadLines(inFile).Select(line => line.Split('^')[0]));
```

Comment: You forgot `File` before `WriteAllLines`. But I didn't downvote for that.

Comment: @Yuck : ReadLines() is much better (less memory) here.

Comment: +1 from me as well. Could you provide some context to the memory usage between ReadLines and ReadAllLines?

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon it's described over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (maybe not the memory usage but at least the difference)

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon - ReadLines is a later (Fx4) addition that produces the lines lazily as an `IEnumerable<>`. This solution can handle a multi-GB file with only 1 string in memory at a time. ReadAllLines() produces a `string[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void Method()
    {
        string originPath = "";
        string savePath = "";

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(originPath);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string digits = line.Substring(0, 3);   //If you are sure it will always be 3 digits.
                digits = line.Split('^').FirstOrDefault();

                if (digits != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(digits);
                }
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the substring if you're going to split the line anyway.  You should be using a `using` construct rather than explicitly calling `Close()`. Further, with your pattern you should have called `Dispose()` as well.

Comment: @Yuck if we're sure that the line will always start with three digits, then we should keep the substring and skip the split.  Further nitpicking: we should skip "if digits != null" because it will never be null.

Comment: @phoog : It could be null if there is an empty line. The split will return an empty array and the FirstOrDefault() will return null because the collection is empty. Yuck :As for your using, I agree that it would be a good improvement. I will modify the answer.

Comment: @gretro if `line` is an empty string, then `line.Split('^')` will return a 1-element array containing an empty string.  It will not return an empty array.